# Self-fixing 'broken' floating behavior in Google Chome

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-float

I am experiencing some weird floating-behavior in Google Chrome within the first responsive project I am working on.

I've uploaded an anonymized version of my responsive header here: http://files.uiux.de/140618_header/

Whenever I visit this page on a desktop with Google Chrome, having no cache of the page, the contact-information in the right-hand corner seem to have a margin-top and 'broken' floating of the icons. As soon as I reload the Page, the position is automatically fixed.

I can reproduce this behavior by resizing the Chrome window to it's narrowest setting, refreshing the page and then resize Chrome until the contact-information shows up again.

I am baffled by this behavior. Firefox and Safari work just fine. Can someone explain to me what is happening there and maybe offer a possible solution?

Here's a screenshot of both the initial rendering and the one after refreshing.

[image]

Comment: It looks like the icons are pushing the content to the bottom. You might be able to solve this if you set a min-width for the ul or li

Comment: @Huangism Thank you for the hint, but I think that this is not the issue. I've edited my post to include a screenshot of the initial rendering and the one after refreshing.

Comment: Loads fine for me the first time.

Comment: I have had many issue with webkit based browsers. I think setting a min-width or a width would work while you seek out the reason why this happens. I was able to reproduce it on first load and while loading on smaller screen then resizing it to large

Comment: Can you reproduce it if your `ul.info` comes before `a.logo` in the markup?

Comment: Thank you all so much for your help! I can actually not reproduce it, when i place the ul.info before the logo in the markup, as ajp15243 suggested.

I also found out that this only happens as long as jQuery is included in the page. Strange behavior but it now does work. Thanks again!